# Why does TortoiseHg hides some revisions by default?

Tags: windows-7, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have to click in the radio button `All` to see all revisions. 
Why some are hidden by default?
How to show all by default?

I have TortoiseHg 1.1.5 with Mercurial-1.7, Python-2.6.4, PyGTK-2.16.0, GTK-2.16.6 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following in the source code: http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/src/9d917274ab7e/tortoisehg/hgtk/history.py

```
class FilterBar(gtklib.SlimToolbar):
    'Filter Toolbar for repository log'

    def __init__(self, tooltips, filter_mode, branch_names, repo):
        gtklib.SlimToolbar.__init__(self, tooltips)
        self.filter_mode = filter_mode
        self.buttons = {}
        self.handlers = {}

        self.all = gtk.RadioButton(None, _('All'))
        self.all.set_active(True)
        self.append_widget(self.all, padding=0)
        self.buttons['all'] = self.all
```

Comment: In case anyone looks in the first version of your answer, I should say that ignoring max diff size didn't work for me

Comment: @XMLforDummies: +1 Yes, in my first version. I was looking at change-sets. When I reread your question, I understood, it was different.So I looked at the source code for the filters with GTK buttons and I edited to include the source code because the behavior seemed all right. You did see that the behavior got fixed when you upgraded to latest revision. :)

Comment: The problem began to happen again